# Does the Vietoris functor preserve compact sobriety?

Tags: general-topology

**Situation:** The Vietoris functor $\mathbb{V}$ is an endofunctor on the category of topological spaces. Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a topological space, then $\mathbb{V}\mathcal{X}$ is the set of closed subsets of $\mathcal{X}$ topologized by the subbase
$$
\Box U := \{ V \in \mathbb{V}\mathcal{X} \mid V \subseteq U \}, \qquad \Diamond U := \{ V \in \mathbb{V}\mathcal{X} \mid U \cap V \neq \emptyset \},
$$
where $U$ ranges over the opens of $\mathcal{X}$.

**Question:** Suppose $\mathcal{X}$ is compact and sober. Is $\mathbb{V}\mathcal{X}$ compact and sober?

**Thoughts:** It is known that $\mathbb{V}$ preserves compactness. I have never found a proof that states $\mathbb{V}$ preserves sobriety, so I don't think this is true. So I wonder whether the additional compactness "helps" the preservation of sobriety.

Comment: The preservation of compactness is a corollary of the Alexander subbase theorem.

Comment: Normally we only take the non-empty closed subsets. Otherwise, $\mathbb{V}X$ always has $\emptyset$ as an isolated point (as $\Box \emptyset= \emptyset$ and also $\Diamond \emptyset= \emptyset$.). With the usual non-empty closed subsets definition, we have that $X$ connected and $T_1$ implies $\mathbb{V}X$ is connected e.g.

Comment: I meant $\Box\emptyset= \{\emptyset\} = \Diamond \emptyset$ of course.

Comment: Your definition of sober = $T_0$ plus every irreducible closed set is the closure of a singleton?

Comment: Hmm, in the articles I've read the empty closed set is not ruled out. Does that make a difference? Sober is indeed $T_0$ plus every irreducible closed set is the closure of a singleton.

Comment: It's not too hard to see that $\mathbb{V}X$ is always $T_0$ anyway, regardless of $X$. It's $T_1$ iff $X$ is.

Comment: These cases are easy indeed. Compact + $T_2$ is also preserved. Unfortunately there are strict implications $T_2 \Rightarrow$ sober $\Rightarrow T_0$, and the sober property is incomparable with $T_1$. The problem with sobriety (I think) is its non-intuitive definition...